# Angular is not defined when using QRCodeModule

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using Angular7 and I need to add the usage of Qr-code.

This is what I did:
1) I tried to install it using the command:

```
npm install angular7-qrcode --save
```

But it did not work out:

```
Not found: angular7-qrcode@latest
```

although this is the command I found in the documentation

2) then I installed it using slightly modified command:

```
npm install angular-qrcode@latest --save
```

And it was installed

3) Next I imported the module into the app.module:

```
import { QRCodeModule } from 'angular-qrcode';
```

And specified it in the imports […, QRCodeModule]

But shortly after that the browser displayed the strange exception:

Uncought reference error: angular is not defined at object /nodule-modules/angular-qrcode/angular-qrcode.js
at __webpack__require
at Module …/app.module.ts

Why is that and how to fix it? I am surprised that most of the angular components do not work on the installation stage and create the similar problems.

Comment: hey! Is your issue got fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The second library that you are trying to use is an "AngularJS" directive not "Angular". Thats why it is giving you that error. The npm site of this package says "An AngularJS directive to create QR Codes using Kazuhiko Arase’s qrcode-generator library." So it wont help you in your project. You have to use an Angular package.

You can use this one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-qrcode